# Dependensies of program and install libraries

Tags: linux, installation, libraries

In my Linux Mint i have a program, an executable file.
With ldd in terminal i can take dependensies of this executable.
    ldd file
When move program in another system it dont runs.

ldd file gives something like ...

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc2a36d000)
libwx_gtk2u_stc-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_stc-3.0.so.0 (0x00007f2919d55000)
libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0 (0x00007f291996f000)
libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 (0x00007f29190f5000)
libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 (0x00007f2918c63000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f291898e000)
```

...............

How i can know all that libraries and install only it needs to run to other system.

Using objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED i can get only libs that i need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ldd's output says that you have got all the library dependencies installed on your system.

The reason it doesn't run on another system is most likely due to the difference in linking table of those libraries, so your program simply cannot find symbols it is looking for by that addresses.

As a simple solution, I would recommend to recompile program on a new machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When i move program to other system and instal many libs it runs. But this OS is in vitrual machine. When program must send to a frient , it must runs. How i must know what i done before in OS if i did not track history? There must a way to knew whitch libs must install in OS for this program to runs.

Comment: You can check needed libs with ldd, like you did above. Sorry, I didn't understand your other question.

Comment: Also couldn't you please clarify "program doesn't run"? It may be due to different reason.

Comment: Dont runs means that moving program execute file to other same OS and execute it ./my_program ./my_program: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_stc-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. But if dependesies are many, i will try to have install from coding automatically.

Comment: How to install libwx_gtk2u_stc-3.0 library?

Comment: sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-0v5

Comment: there is no `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_stc-3.0.so.0` file?